# Cómo convertir un array de tipo string a int

Tags: java, html, netbeans, servlets

Estoy trabajando en un servlet en java NetBeans y le estoy enviando información de una página HTML, en la página tengo 3 inputs:

`<input name="cantidad" type="number">`

`<input name="cantidad" type="number">`

`<input name="cantidad" type="number">`

En el Servlet tengo el método post y el override y también lo siguiente:

```
String [] Cantidad = request.getParametersValues("cantidad");
```

Pero quiero obtener la variable Cantidad como tipo entero, pero no sé como hacerlo

Intenté hacer esto:

```
Int [] Cantidad = request.getParametersValues("cantidad");
```

Pero me da un error

Comment: Saludos. Espero te sirva https://coderanch.com/t/381786/java/Pls-convert-string-array-int

Comment: No me funcionó, podrías ayudarme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pasar informacion normalmente llega como cadenas de texto, asi hayas enviado un numero, pero antes deberias cerciorarte de que efectivamente tu variable:

```
String [] Cantidad = request.getParametersValues("cantidad");
```

Tenga contenido, y que el contenido sea directamente parseable a un numero, de lo contrario solamente estaras saltando de **excepcion** en **excepcion**.

O aun peor, de `error` en `error`.

Asi que te invito a que compruebes primero que si lo que obtienes en `request.getParametersValues("cantidad");` **es un arreglo de strings**, de lo contrario te va a saltar una excepcion muy fuerte, debido a que si cantidad no es un arreglo de `strings` si no simplemente un `string` entonces estas asignandole a `Cantidad` tipos que son incoherentes.

Ahora bien, suponiendo que te llega bien la informacion, yo supongo entonces que **te habras confundido y estas asignando el tipo equivocado**, puesto que al leer directamente el nombre de tu variable `Cantidad` no me indica un plural, me indica un singular, por lo tanto idealmente tu arreglo no debería ser un arreglo, solo un simple `String`:

```
String Cantidad = request.getParametersValues("cantidad");
```

Pero tu no deseas un `String`, deseas un `Int`, por lo tanto lo que puedes hacer es guardar directamente un `Int` y parsear el valor a un entero con `Integer.parseInt`:

```
int Cantidad = Integer.parseInt(request.getParametersValues("cantidad"));
```

Si esto no funciona puede significar tres cosas:

- No estas obteniendo nada cuando llamas a `request.getParametersValues("cantidad");` o lo que obtienes es `null`.
- Estas obteniendo algo, pero su tipo difiere de `String`, por lo que no es parseable a un `Int` o `int`.
- Estas oteniendo un `String`, pero el formato de numero guardado en el `String` es incorrecto y por lo tanto no es parseable, por ejemplo:

  ```
  Integer.parseInt("2G");
  Integer.parseInt("2,6");
  ```

Te invito a revisar este tipo de cosas, asi quizas puedas resolver tus inconvenientes...

Una cosa mas, si de verdad tu arreglo `Cantidad` es un array de `Strings` ya que asi lo estas manejando y deseas seguirlo manejando en ese formato entonces lo que puedes hacer es primero recibir el array en formato `String` como lo haces y luego crear otro array del mismo tamaño que almacenara la misma información pero en formato `int`:

```
String [] Cantidad = request.getParametersValues("cantidad");
int[] valores = new int[Cantidad.length];

for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){
   valores[i] = Integer.parseInt(Cantidad[i]);
}
```

De esta manera el ciclo se encarga de asignar todos los valores al nuevo arreglo de ints llamado valores pero con un formato directamente de ints.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho la respuesta

Comment: Podrías ayudarme a realizar una suma de los valores que estoy obteniendo?

Comment: En unos minutos te ayudo vale :v

Comment: Si muchas gracias, yo espero

Comment: Que valores deseas sumar?, si son los valores del arreglo de ints que esperas tener entonces basta con crear una nueva variable de tipo int fuera del ciclo for que se realiza al final de mi respuesta e iniciarla en `0` y dentro del ciclo for seria hacer algo como: `resultado += valores[i]` recuerda que debe estar despues de la linea donde parseas y asignas `valores[i]`, el simbolo `+=` se usa para añadir a lo que ya se tenia en una variable otro contenido, como se trata de numeros seria igual a sumarle a lo que ya tiene la variable otro valor y guardar el resultado.

Comment: Yes. asi seria.

Comment: ```int[] valores = new int[Cantidad.length];```

```int resultado=0;```

```for(int i = 0; i < valores.length; i++){

   ```valores[i] = Integer.parseInt(Cantidad[i]);```
   
   ```resultado+=Cantidad[i];```
   
}

Comment: Algo así?, Pero me da un error me dice que son variables incompatibles

Comment: Porque no puedes usar `Cantidad` recuerda que de ahi partiste (un array de Strings), en su lugar debes usar `valores[i]` para asignar a `resultado`, puesto que `valores[i]` ya es el que contiene los numeros en formato `int` recuerda que si te fue de ayuda mi respuesta puedes darla como aceptada dandole al boton que parece un chulo.

Comment: En el input inserté 1,2,3 y la suma debería ser 6 pero primero suma ```1+2 =3``` y después ```3+3=6``` todo está bien pero digamos que necesito el resultado final, quiero mostrar sólo el 6 pero al usar el PrintWriter y mostrar la variable resultado me muestra lo que te dije anteriormente, pero solo necesito mostrar el resultado final, cómo le haría? Espero puedas ayudarme, ya que te estoy molestando mucho

Comment: No necesitas usar PrintWriter para imprimir informacion, puedes mostrar el resultado en consola como para debugear usando un `System.out.println(variable);` ah y debes hacerlo por supuesto fuera del ciclo, puesto que si lo haces dentro de este recuerda que se ejecuta varias vecez, por lo que enrealidad estas imprimiendo todo ese proceso cada vez que se ejecuta el ciclo.

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio, ya pude terminar la tarea que me habían dejado